# Failed to change axes position in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I want to ask, i am making a php program (graph) using highcharts.

What I want to ask is how to swap series1, series2, series3, to 0,1,2,3,4.
How to change its position.
example code :

```
jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/TfvGp/
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want. What do you mean by "swap series1, series2, series3, to 0,1,2,3,4"?

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for is index options http://jsfiddle.net/TfvGp/188/